# Phonegap iOS: how to remove status bar when hotspot overlay is active?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

My Phonegap app (running on iOS 8.1, iPhone 5) has a typical black status bar at the top of the page. Usually this works perfectly.

When I run the app with the device's personal hotspot on, the blue personal hotspot message appears, as intended. It does not overlay the app, as intended. However, the original status bar is now positioned after the personal hotspot message, and is an empty black bar with nothing in it. It seems like the original status bar was removed, but its container was not.

Is there a way to get rid of this empty black bar when the hotspot is on?

To clarify. There is still a status bar at the original place when the hotspot is on. It just appears blue and part of the hotspot message.

My HTML looks exactly like the code snippet under the heading 'Basic Template' on [this page](http://goratchet.com/getting-started). It's just a typical HTML file.

I'm using the Phonegap StatusBar plugin, and added just this one line of code in the Phonegap `config.xml` file:

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide with the code snippets you have tried so far to help out understanding of your question.

Comment: Ok I'll collect the HTML and JS code snippets. But basically it's just a starter Ratchet.js app with the Cordova StatusBar plugin set to no overlay.